# create a custom view canvas that draws a collection of custom moveable Rect views

Tags: android

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a dynamic collection of custom views to display as movable rectangles inside a canvas.  The canvas is a bar with bar stools and I want the restaurant manager to be able to create the layout of his/her bar that other pages can utilize.

I have it working, but not well and the individual "BarSpots" won't move and the onTouchEvent of the ViewBarSpot isn't firing - however - the onTouchEvent of the ViewBarCanvas IS firing.  What am I missing??

**ActivityBarLayout:**

```
private FrameLayout flCanvas;
List<BarSpot> dbBarSpots;
...
private void LoadBar(List<BarSpot> barSpots) {
    try{
        flCanvas.removeAllViews();
        View viewBarCanvas = new ViewBarCanvas(getApplicationContext(), barSpots);
        flCanvas.addView(viewBarCanvas);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        LogUtil.log(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**ViewBarCanvas:**

```
Context mContext;
public List<ViewBarSpot> mBoxs;
public List<BarSpot> mBarSpots;


public ViewBarCanvas(Context context, List<BarSpot> barSpots) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mBarSpots = barSpots;
    mBoxs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BarSpot barSpot : barSpots) {
        mBoxs.add(new ViewBarSpot(context, barSpot));
    }
    init(null);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for (ViewBarSpot viewBarSpot : mBoxs) {
        canvas.drawRect(viewBarSpot.mRectangle, viewBarSpot.mPaintBackground);
        canvas.drawRect(viewBarSpot.mRectangle, viewBarSpot.mStrokePaint);
        canvas.drawText(viewBarSpot.mText, viewBarSpot.mStart, viewBarSpot.mStart + viewBarSpot.mNumberOfCharacters, viewBarSpot.mRectangle.exactCenterX(), viewBarSpot.mRectangle.exactCenterY(), viewBarSpot.mPaintText);
    }

}
```

**ViewBarSpot:**

```
public float mPosX;
public float mPosY;
public float mLastTouchX;
public float mLastTouchY;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final float x = event.getX();
    final float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            // Remember where we started
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            // Calculate the distance moved
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            // Move the object
            if (mRectangle.left < x && mRectangle.right > x && mRectangle.top < y && mRectangle.bottom > y) {
                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;
                // Invalidate to request a redraw
                postInvalidate();
            }


            // Remember this touch position for the next move event
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;


            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            /*realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    mBarSpot.setPositionLeft((int)mPosX - SQUARE_SIZE/2);
                    mBarSpot.setPositionRight((int)mPosX + SQUARE_SIZE/2);
                    mBarSpot.setPositionTop((int)mPosY - SQUARE_SIZE/2);
                    mBarSpot.setPositionBottom((int)mPosY + SQUARE_SIZE/2);
                }

            });*/
    }
    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}

public ViewBarSpot(Context context, BarSpot barSpot) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mBarSpot = barSpot;
    mText = barSpot.getDescription();

    mRectangle = new Rect(mBarSpot.getPositionLeft(), mBarSpot.getPositionTop(), mBarSpot.getPositionLeft() + SQUARE_SIZE, mBarSpot.getPositionTop()+ SQUARE_SIZE);

    mPaintBackground = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintBackground.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.themeColor1));
    mPaintBackground.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    mStrokePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mStrokePaint.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.themeColor3));
    mStrokePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

    mPaintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintText.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.themeColor3));
    mPaintText.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE);
    mPaintText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    mNumberOfCharacters = mPaintText.breakText(mText,true, SQUARE_SIZE,null);
    mStart = (mText.length()- mNumberOfCharacters)/2;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


}
```